# GRUB: how find partition number (hd0,x)?

Tags: linux, grub

i am playing with grub and i change the root using:

`root (hda,x)`

how can i know what's **x** for `/dev/sda7` ?

`fdisk -l`

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        1958    15727603+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2            1959        7476    44323335    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5            1959        4569    20972826    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6            4570        5352     6289416   83  Linux
/dev/sda7            6373        7119     6000246   83  Linux
/dev/sda8            7120        7476     2867571   83  Linux
/dev/sda9            5353        6135     6289416   83  Linux
/dev/sda10           6136        6372     1903671   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

the problem is that in **Gparted** view, the order is not like sda5, sda6, sda7, ...
but the order is like:

- sda6
- sda9
- sda10
- sda7
- sda8

so what's **x** for `/dev/sda7` ?

Answer (score 21):

First off, you need to realize that in grub, it does not use normal linux hard drive identifiers.  Instead, the letters correlate to numbers, starting with zero (i.e. hda = hd0, hdb = hd1, etc).

Secondly, in grub-legacy, the partition number starts at 0, not 1 like in Linux, so subtract 1 from the linux partition number. And in grub2, it [starts at 1](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html).

An example is: hda1 = (hd0, 0)

Finally, grub does not differentiate between hd and sd devices, so everything is labeled hd.

Thus, in your case, your grub entry for /dev/sda6 should read (hd0, 5)

Comment: thanks, is it 5 because the extends start from 4?
is it so:
sda1 -> 0
sda2 ->
sda5 -> 4
sda6 -> 5
sda7 -> 6

Comment: I exactly tried what jonathan suggested, mine was on `hd2,4` and i had to put `sdb4` to make it work

Comment: In Grub 2 it has changed, `/dev/sda6` is `(hd0, 6)`: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Naming-convention.html

Answer (score 11):

Easiest way to be sure is from grub cli and using tab completion.

start by typing... root (hd0,

then hit [tab]
The tab completion should then list the partitions available.
pick the one you think makes most sense close off the parentheses and on the next line type
kernel /

then hit [tab] again...  if the files and directory structure look right you picked the right one... if not.. back up and redo the root line.

Comment: Did not work for me, using openSUSE Leap 42.1 and GRUB Legacy (GRUB 0.97)

Comment: This is helpful in my situation but my partitions (I have 11) list scrolled off-screen and I can't SHIFT+PGUP to see the first ones.  Is there a way to list the partitions specifically?  like `type (hd1,gpt2)` or something?

Comment: I just found a `set pager=1` command.  I think that will work, never mind.

Comment: From grub cli, you can also type `ls` to list available drives and partitions

Comment: @fymita How do I enter a grub cli inside my Linux box? I mean, not at boot time, but when using a terminal. Is it possible?